# I am getting error when i run an azure ML experiment in Excel

Tags: excel, azure, machine-learning

```
Error! {"error":{"code":"LibraryExecutionError","message":"Module execution encountered an internal library error.","details":[{"code":"TableSchemaColumnCountMismatch","target":" (AFx Library)","message":"data: The table column count (0) must match the schema column count (17)."}]}}
```

[image]

Can you  help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the original data file you used to train your Machine Learning Model does not have the same number of columns as the test file that you are using in Excel to make your predictions using the Test Dataset.   If you look at the **Schema** of the Predictive Algorithm you are calling within Excel you will see which columns are "extra" in the original Dataset.  Although you can select columns out with the Azure Machine Learning module, "Select Columns in Dataset", this does not prevent the excluded columns from being detected by the Web service you deploy and then ending up in the schema of the Predictive Algorithm you deployed in Azure ML when you call it in Excel.  When you are in Excel with the test Dataset that you will use your predictive web service on, make sure the columns in the test Dataset match one to one with the dataset you used to train your machine learning model (with the exception of the scored Label column that will have the results of the predictive algorithm on the Azure Machine Learning website).  Edit the **training Dataset** by removing columns you are going to exclude with the Select Columns in Dataset Module and then upload this edited dataset and use it to retrain your Machine Learning Model before you deploy it.  This should get it to work.